# Reducer logs 'deleted' but it still exists in firestore database...?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, action

'id' gets sent through action and reducer and logs out 'deleted' but doesn't actually delete from firestore database...

clientlist:

```
class Clients extends Component {

  handleClick = (id) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    this.props.deleteClient(id)
  }

  render() {
    const {clientList} = this.props
    return (
      <div className="container mt-5 text-center">
        <h2>Here Are Your List of Clients...</h2>
        {clientList && clientList.map(client => {
          return(
            <div key={client.id}>
              <div className="my-2">
                Client Name: {client.name} | Client Price: ${client.price}
                <button className="ml-2" onClick={() => {this.handleClick(client.id)}}>x</button>
              </div>      
            </div>

          )
        })}
        <AddClient/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    clientList : state.firestore.ordered.clientList,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return{
    deleteClient : (id) => dispatch(deleteClient(id)) 
  }
}

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  firestoreConnect([
    {collection: 'clientList', orderBy: 'name'},
  ])
)(Clients)
```

action:

```
export const deleteClient = (id) => {
    return(dispatch, getState, {getFirestore, getFirebase}) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        firestore.collection("clientList").doc(id).delete().then(() => {
            dispatch({type: 'DELETE CLIENT'})
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type: 'DELETE CLIENT ERROR', err})
        });

    }     
}
```

let me know if you need any other code or information. ps, there is no error logging out into the console.

Comment: Try changing '/{id}' with '/${id}' instead.

Comment: This also logs 'client deleted' in the console but it doesn't actually remove from firebase.

Comment: if you are using ES6 syntax then dynamic variable in string you need template literals \`/${id}\`

Comment: `/${id}` or `${id`} or (id) all go through without an error in the console, but don't delete in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  `.doc(id)` because id has to be string.

I dont think you need `/` inside `doc`.

[Check the api.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data)

```
export const deleteClient = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    return(dispatch, getState, {getFirestore, getFirebase}) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        firestore.collection('clientList').doc(id).delete().then(() =>{
            dispatch({type: 'DELETE CLIENT'})
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type: 'DELETE CLIENT ERROR', err})
        })
    }     
}
```

Comment: This also logs 'client deleted' in the console but it doesn't actually remove from firebase.

Comment: did you remove `/` from your `doc` ?

Comment: or even just simply like this `firestore.collection('clientList').doc(id).delete()`

Comment: I actually did that initially and was getting this error: FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: 0.7200573007083342

Comment: so what is the value of id inside `deleteIcon` ? your id has to be string

Comment: I think its just a set of digits.. it came from Math.random()

Comment: @josephT you need to provide the correct id of the doc that you want to remove, it cannot be random.

Comment: can I use something like id.toString() ?

Comment: It cannot be random ID, it has to be the id that you take from firebase, which is String

Comment: In firebase, the 'id' field is === to the 'id' that i am transferring to the action creator

Comment: The firebase field states that my value is a Number. The toString() method changes my id in react to a string but even then nothing happens. If I change it back to a Number and do `/${id}` or `${id}` or `(id)` it still doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191219/discussion-between-josepht-and-alexandr-zavalii).